# Mount drives as world writable using Disks tool

Tags: permissions, mount

I've used the Disks tool to mount two drives I'm using for external shares. They've both mounted as world-readable, but I would like them to mount as world-writable as it fits my use case.

I know I can solve this on the command line, but I'm wondering if it can be solved in the GUI application also (for future reference). I've already tried editing the mount options and putting `rw` in the comma delimited list of options as I assumed that would work like it would in the terminal, but the drive still mounts as world-readable only (and owned by root).

Is there a way to solve this or can it only be mounted world-writable via the terminal?

Comment: What are the permissions of the mount point?

Comment: What file system(s) is/are there on the drive(s)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and answer the above questions and post the contents of your current ´ fstab`